# Using If Then Else statement in ArcMap ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, field-calculator, if-else

I have a model that adds several fields, two which are manual inputs (County Name and User). I am manipulating several parcel layers (approx 90 counties).

In my model, one field takes the state and county ID's and (FIPS) calcs them together. The next field is a manual input of the county name (Which I enter). I want to write a if then statement in a calc value of this field from another feature.

Essentially in my parcel layer, I want the county name to automatically calculated based off the FIPS column in my parcel layer and in my county layer. So If FIPS = FIPS (From my county layer), then calc county name (in my parcel layer). Is this possible?

Comment: I think you'll need to join the features to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't say which version of ArcGIS, but it sounds like you could make use of the Join Field tool here (or Add Join, Calculate Field, Remove Join):  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm  Usually, I'd use cursors for this, but you said you needed a 'modelbuilder' solution.

Comment: ArcMap 10.2.1, I guess I was over thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Help page called [Using If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm) which I think you should review:

> In ModelBuilder, if-then-else logic can be implemented by writing a
>   script tool that tests some condition, then outputs two Boolean
>   variables that describe the true and false condition and incorporating
>   this script tool in a model. As an alternative to writing a script
>   tool, you can also use the Calculate Value tool to test the condition
>   and output a Boolean.